# How map Two List properties of same class in Entity framefork 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

My Class is

```
public class DocumentSale 
{
   public List<DocumentSale> FollowDocuments {get; set;}
   public List<DocumentSale> BaseDocuments {get; set;}
}
```

How to map it on entity framework? I get an error

> "FK_dbo.DocumentSaleDocumentSales_public.saledocument_DocumentSa" for relation "DocumentSaleDocumentSales" already exists

My Database is postgres 9.4.9

Comment: Also class DocumentSale has an id field, marked as [Key]

Comment: You have to use InverseProperty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what I was needed:

```
public class DocumentSale 
{
   public List<DocumentSale> FollowDocuments {get; set;}
   public List<DocumentSale> BaseDocuments {get; set;}
}

  modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentSale>()
        .HasMany<DocumentSale>(c => c.baseDocuments)
        .WithMany(c => c.followUpDocuments)
        .Map(
        cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("followdocid");
                cs.MapRightKey("basedocid");
                cs.ToTable("basefollow");
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
public class DocumentSale
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? FollowDocumentId { get; set; }
    public int? BaseDocumentId { get; set; }

    public virtual DocumentSale FollowDocument { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentSale BaseDocument { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FollowDocumentId))]
    public virtual List<DocumentSale> FollowDocuments { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(BaseDocumentId))]
    public virtual List<DocumentSale> BaseDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Message=One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Comment: DocumentSale_baseDocuments_Source_DocumentSale_baseDocuments_Target: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'BaseDocumentId' on entity 'DocumentSale' does not match the type of property 'id' on entity 'DocumentSale' in the referential constraint 'DocumentSale_baseDocuments'.

Comment: DocumentSale_followUpDocuments_Source_DocumentSale_followUpDocuments_Target: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'FollowDocumentId' on entity 'DocumentSale' does not match the type of property 'id' on entity 'DocumentSale' in the referential constraint 'DocumentSale_followUpDocuments'.

Comment: That error said that your Id property has different type compare to BaseDocumentId. Maybe your Id property has type `long` or `Guid`? Also I tested my code in my project and everething works as expected.